# Enable MathJax for Woodworking

Tags: support

While I don't see this site needing to express a lot of equations, I can see where we're going to have a lot of use of fractions and numbers with associated units.

For example, all of the quarter and octal (?) fractions are frequently used in measurements.  Dropping into 16ths, 32nds, and 64ths is common as well.

Having MathJax enabled will make it easier for us to indicate those dimensions.

So can we have MathJax turned on for Woodworking, please?

Answer (score 10):

I agree, it is seldom that we actually work with round numbers in this field.  That being said, MathJax does add some processing time when rendering the page.

What we may be able to do is have an extension added to the markdown renderer which allows fractions to be displayed nicely.  When I asked around inside SE, this was the best answer given to avoid loading such a huge library (MathJax has a LOT of stuff we'd never use) when we're only using one very small feature of that library.

**The markdown solution seems like a much better choice.**

Comment: I don't know the MathJax syntax but I assume it'd be similar to latex. If so, markdown syntax would probably be simpler to write.

Comment: I agree; MathJax is overkill and inappropriate for this site.

Comment: What would be entailed in the "markdown solution"?

Comment: The request has been mentioned to the dev team, they'll see about whether it is something that could be implemented or if it is really better to use MathJax instead.  I'm sure we'll hear more about it after the site is in public beta.

Comment: Is this in place or not?